# A mod @-mentioned me but I didn't get a notification

Tags: support, bug, notifications

On [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/165526) I received a [comment](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/165526/i-believe-i-have-a-clever-idea-tool-that-should-be-widely-adopted-by-the-researc#comment445771_165526) from a moderator, for which I didn't get a notification.

This is the comment:

> @MatthewChristopherBartsh - It has almost certainly aged out of being a hot network question by now. Old questions, especially those with such a negative score, will indeed get very few views. The 1/hour you see are probably due to your bounty.

Comment: Even if they didn't @-mention you, you should have had a notification (I assume you mean the red indicator on your inbox) . given there weren't any notifications pending for that same post. Notifications for the same question roll-up in one. You can see their response [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=responses), right?

Comment: @rene No I  mean the entry in the in in tray that has the red indicators. Not sure how what number was on the red indicator. Yes, I see it where you linked to.

Comment: And [here as well](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=inbox), right?

Comment: @rene No, I don't see it there.

Comment: Can you visit https://academia.stackexchange.com/topbar/inbox and check if the comment is present there? (don't be alarmed that it doesn't look correctly styled, it is not meant to be requested this way)

Comment: @rene No. I don't see it there, either.

Comment: That is super weird. No idea what happened there. This needs an developer with access to server logs to figure out what failed and why.